# Rails Rspec `require': cannot load such file -- rails_helper (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to use Rspec for my test. When I run

```
$ rspec mytest_spec.rb
```

I get the following error due to the

```
/home/bastien/.merbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails_helper (LoadError)
```

I have tried many things and somehow if I run

```
rspec spec
```

or

```
bundle exec rspec
```

from the folder where my .rspec file is I do not get any error. I have created an app just to dry test this issue (I created a new rail app, added rspec in my Gemfile, run the bundle install command and the rspec:install command, generated a scaffold and run the tests. Could anyone explain to me why I get this issue and how I can get rid of it? Do I do something wrong when I try to run only one single spec? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are getting that error because you're trying to call your spec like this...

```
rspec mytest_spec.rb
```

You need to call it like this **from your app's root folder** , not inside the spec folder. So first get in the right folder

```
cd ~/
cd path_to_your_rails_app
```

Then call your spec

```
rspec spec/the_rest_of_the_path_to_your_spec/mytest_spec.rb
```

for instance

```
rspec spec/models/mytest_spec.rb
```

Answer (score 6):

For others who find this:

I got this error, `'require': cannot load such file -- rails_helper (LoadError)`, when I had included the rspec-rails gem  but hadn't run `rails generate rspec:install` which generates the `spec/rails_helper.rb` file. So if the other solution doesn't help you, make sure you've done that.

Comment: This answer solved my problem, thanks. I need to RTFM more thoroughly :-)

Answer (score 2):

For those that the answers above didn't help:

You just need to add `gem 'rexml'` to your `Gemfile.rb`, run `bundle install` and try again.